# How to use Chart Points to another method

Tags: c#

I have chart in a windows form application where I plot different signals imported from a csv file.
I now want to create a button that will enable a movable vertical annotation and  show all Points at a label.

My problem is that I cannot use my point collection dp in the button method.

```
  Series s = chart1.Series.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            s.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;  // make the points stand out
            s.MarkerSize = 3;
        }    
     for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)

        {
            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();

            dp.SetValueXY(r, checkedSignal]);
         chart1.Series[CheckedSignal].Points.Add(dp);
        }
```

And the other function is like this :

```
private void chart1_AnnotationPositionChanging(object sender, AnnotationPositionChangingEventArgs e)
    {  if (sender == VA) RA.X = VA.X - RA.Width / 2;

        
        int pt1 = (int)e.NewLocationX;

 double step = (s.Points[pt1 + 1].YValues[0] - s.Points[pt1].YValues[0]);
```

}

I get always this Exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Well, what does the  debugger tell you: What is and what isn't null? sender? VA? s..?

Comment: the debugger tells that s is null

Comment: `s` being a Series?? Check if you accidentally have declared an extra instance of it instead of just a reference to the actual chart series..

Comment: s is a Series. This Series is created in a function where I import a csv file, and I want to use its points to another method. I want something like to make Series s global

Comment: Well from the tiny snippets we see I still have a hunch that there really are two declaration for `s`. You create it in a 1st function and add it to the chart. ok. But: the name you use there is local and will be out of scope afterwards. So: How can you still use it in the 2nd function?? You need a new declaration which you probably or else it won't compile but __you also need to point it to the series you want__, maybe líke so: `Series s = chart1.Series[someName]`.

Comment: Since you assigned the name in a slightly mysterious way (`checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString()`) I can't tell what it is..  Simply caling it `s` doesn't mean it points to the series you created before..

Comment: You are right, the s Series was declared twice. Do you have any idea how can I create it on the one method and then use it to the other ?

Comment: All the Series you show are referenced in the chart.Series colection. - The simplest way is to keep a reference at class level, either to the Series or to its Name. Or decide on a way on how to find the series you want to work with in the chart.Series collection.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot